# C# WPF. Хранение приватных данных

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток!

Такой вопрос: допустим у меня есть данные от входа в SQL DB. Мне их надо где-то хранить. А вот где? 
Как это правильно делается? 
Ибо хранить в коде - бред. Обычный реверс раскроет все карты.

Помогите пожалуйста!)

Comment: Не храните, пусть пользователь вводит сам свой логин/пароль

Comment: Я всё понимаю. Это да. Но допустим пользователь ввёл свои данные, а мне нужно проверить их на валидность. Собсна - мне нужно сделать запрос в SQL БД, а что бы его сделать - мне нужны логин и пароль от БД. Вот их то надо где-то хранить

Comment: Заводите пользователя в БД и пусть пользователь программы заходит в БД под этим пользователем, а не все под одной учеткой (админской еще небось)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не храните данные. используйте хеши. логин можно сохранять по подтверждению пользователя в любом файле конфигурации. пароли рекомендуется не хранить вовсе. пользователь отправляет данные формы -> пароль хешируется, шифруется, отправляется.